# Flutter and ReceivePort: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class with this code in it:

```dart
class GeofenceManager {
  ReceivePort geofencingMessagePort = ReceivePort();

  Stream<String> get events {
    return geofencingMessagePort.map((event) => event.toString());
  }
  ...
```

And in my UI I have a `StreamBuilder` like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    var geofenceManager = Provider.of<GeofenceManager>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      initialData: "Waiting ...",
      stream: geofenceManager.events,
      ...
```

But it's not working. When I run the app I get this error:

```
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

The first build of the UI works, but if I second build is triggered I get the error. I've tried using `asBroadcastStream()` but it's not solved the problem.

So I'm a bit stuck, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working by adding a `StreamController` and listening to the port rather than exposing it. So my code now looks like this:

```dart
class GeofenceManager {
  ReceivePort geofencingMessagePort = ReceivePort();
  StreamController<String> _eventController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  
  Stream<String> get events {
    return _eventController.stream;
  }

  GeofenceManager._() {
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(_geofencingMessagePort.sendPort, 'geofencing_send_port');
    _geofencingMessagePort.listen((message) {
      _eventController.add(message);
    });
  }

  ...
```

This works but I'm not sure it's the best solution. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.asBroadcastStream(..)` should work. Make sure **not** to call `geofencingMessagePort .asBroadcastStream(..)` multiple times, because that leads to re-subscribing to a single-subscription `ReceivePort` under the hood. See the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html)

> The returned stream will subscribe to this stream when its first subscriber is added

Unfortunately you can't use the getter like in your example

```
Stream<String> get events {
  return geofencingMessagePort.asBroadcastStream();
}
```

because every access to `events` results in calling `asBroadcastStream()` which in turn attempts to re-subscribe to the single-subscription only `geofencingMessagePort`.

Instead, you can assign the broadcast stream to a separate field:

```
ReceivePort _geofencingMessagePort = ReceivePort();
Stream<String> _eventController = _geofencingMessagePort.asBroadcastStream().map((event) => event.toString());
Stream<String> get eventController => _eventController;
```